# SCRIPT1003 error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In my project, I make a require call to a js file to create an object of the file.
For example,

```
require(['directory/hello-js-file'], function(Hello){
    var hello = new Hello();
    hello.show();
});
```

After this block, Hello is undefined. In the IE console, I see this error message, 'SCRIPT1003: Expected ':' File: Function code (13), Line:2, Column:1'
The function looks like this:

```
function anonymous(){
    return eval(arguments[0]);
}
```

I was able to narrow down this issue being originated from two functions (Contents have been modified but the logic is same.):

```
bindDetail: function($view){
    var self = this;
    var details = object.details;    // object is a global variable
    for(var i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
        if(self.hasData(details[i])){
            // doSomething
        }
    }
},
hasData(detail){
    if(detail.data !== undefined && detail.data !== ""){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This issue only arises in IE. This works fine in Chrome.
Can someone please direct me to a solution? Thank you. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, I realized that I was missing the :function tag to hasData. That resolved the issue. :)